# Using SQL Foreign Key Constraints to Stop Rails User Manipulation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Hello my SQL and/or Rails friends.

Let's say we have two models:

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :beds
end

class Bed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hostel
end
```

When my user, a hostel owner, attempts to create a new booking, the params come in like so:

**{bed_id: 12, start_date: "2017-10-13", end_date: "2017-10-15",...}**

The **bed_id** comes from a dropdown menu showing all the current_user's bed names. The id is passed with the rest of the form data. Now, in the BookingsController, I have to manually make sure that a hacker doesn't manipulate the **bed_id** variable to a bed they don't own.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @bed = current_user.beds.where(id: params[:bed_id]).first 

    if @bed
      # create hostel booking
    else
      # this happens when the user willfully changes the bed_id
      # number using DevTools
    end

end
```

I don't mind verifying the user inputs this way, but I was wondering if there's a way to utilize SQL and/or foreign key constraints to make sure that a user doesn't create a booking using a bed that doesn't belong to them?

Here's some pidgin SQL that kind of demonstrates what I'm looking for. Basically, making the database validate that the **user_id** of the **bed_id** being used is that of the current_user's ID.

```
INSERT INTO bookings (start_date, end_date, bed_id, user_id)
VALUES ("2017-10-13", "2017-10-15", 12, 1)
UNLESS (SELECT * FROM beds WHERE id = 12).user_id != current_user.id

# what I'm doing above is verifying that bed #12 has a user_id that 
# is the same as the current user's ID. That way, if a user 
# manipulates the params, SQL catches it.
```

EDIT:
Here's a better question:

In Rails, I can open the console and create a new reservation manually:

```
Booking.new(user_id: 1, bed_id: 12, start: "2017-10-13", end: "2017-10-15")
```

and the database will create the record, even though the bed with ID #12 does not belong to user #1. Is there anyway to make SQL reinforce these constraints?

Comment: how do you know which beds belongs to the user?

Comment: His @OscarLuza. Each bed record has a user_id foreign key. If a user, "Hostel Panama", which has ID = 4, tries to create a booking using bed ID: 12, user_id: 6 (a different hostel), I'd like to have SQL stop that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what was asked, but...
my preferred solution would be to do it in rails, which gives you better control and is platform independent.

(sorry I cannot validate this easily, but it should give you the idea)

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :check_authorisation, only: :create

def check_authorisation
    unless current_user.beds.where(id: params[:bed_id]).first
        flash[:danger] = "You are not authorised to access this section"
        redirect_to home_url # halts request cycle need to adjust home_url to appropriate
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Andy. I like your solution, but it's still keeping the code in the controller. That's what my **if @bed** is doing as well. I'm just wondering if there is some pure SQL that can reject an INSERT if one foreign key doesn't match another.

Comment: Hi Patrick, There will be different implementations based on different database technologies. Assuming your database supports triggers then it should be possible. But what you are suggesting is that you don't trust  "current_user" to be correct either - in which case you have a bigger problem.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thanks for the reply. The only real reason I need this is to make sure that the logged in user doesn't hack the bed_id number using DevTools. It should never happen during regular use since only the logged-in user's beds are to them.